# Video.js text tracks memory leak (WebVTT/VTT)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, video.js

I use **Video Text Tracks** for displaying some advanced live info over the video.
Every few minutes a new video is loaded with its own **.webvtt** file (2-3k lines).

Everything works great except the fact that memory usage constantly increases.

It's a memory leak, for each new video additional **VTTCue** and **TextTrack** recordings are appended to the previous ones.
[image]

Tried many things and ended up with the below approach, I'm out of ideas.

The tracks are added as proposed by [the Video.js documentation](https://videojs.com/guides/text-tracks/#remote-text-tracks) (remote text tracks):

```
player.ready(() => {
  if (videoOptions.subtitles) {
    player.addRemoteTextTrack(
      {
        src: videoOptions.subtitles,
        kind: 'subtitles',
      },
      false,
    );
  }
});
```

And removed before the player dispose:

```
const remoteTextTracks = this.player.remoteTextTracks();
for (let i = remoteTextTracks.length - 1; i >= 0; i -= 1) {
  this.player.removeRemoteTextTrack(remoteTextTracks[i]);
}
```

They are successfully removed from the player but obviously kept in the memory.

How can I tell/direct/force the **GC** to completely remove old text tracks?

Comment: Can you log the player.remoteTextTracks() after you remove it? Looks like the remove function doesn't completely remove it from the list, or maybe the track is still referenced internally by the player, so javascript doesn't consider it to be eligible for garbage collection.

Comment: A proof of concept for this would be very helpful, otherwise it's hard to guess what could remotely be causing a leak.

Comment: In JavaScript you don't have direct access to GC(garbage collector), so removing element doesn't mean immediate trigger GC. When you profile memory, there should be button to trigger GC(in developer tools) or you can try run Chrome with `--js-flags="--expose-gc"` and manually trigger GC `window.gc()` to proof or disproof of memory leak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone comes here struggling with a similar issue, this is the solution I thought it worked well:

```
const remoteTextTracks = this.player.remoteTextTracks();
for (let i = remoteTextTracks.length - 1; i >= 0; i -= 1) {
    
    remoteTextTracks[i].activeCues_.forEach((val, key) => {
        delete remoteTextTracks[i].activeCues_[key];
    });

    remoteTextTracks[i].cues_.forEach((val, key) => {
        delete remoteTextTracks[i].cues_[key];
    });

    if (!isNil(remoteTextTracks[i].lastCue)) {
        delete remoteTextTracks[i].lastCue;
    }

    this.player.removeRemoteTextTrack(remoteTextTracks[i]);
}
```

All the items had to be deleted individually to free up the memory, many other solutions weren't helpful at all.

But after further investigation due to other memory leaks, I ended up with [this](https://github.com/vuejs/core/issues/7408) - the issue was caused by **Vue Dev Tools**, after disabling it everything seemed okay.

Actually, the memory leak existed in the production and it was fixed by approach from the question but because of active Vue Dev Tools, I wasn't aware I fixed it. :|

Answer (score 0):

When using text tracks, try the following to avoid Video.js' memory leak:

```
while (player.remoteTextTracks().length > 0) {
  player.removeRemoteTextTrack(player.remoteTextTracks()[0]);
}
player.remoteTextTracks().forEach(function(track) {
  track.src = '';
  player.removeRemoteTextTrack(track);
});
```